# How can I make a dictionary that contains list of functions as values without running the functions?

Tags: python

```
import turtle as tr
def palito():
   tr.left(90)
   tr.forward(100)
def rayito():
  tr.right(180)
  tr.forward(50)
  tr.left(90)
  tr.forward(50)

con={"a":[palito(), rayito()]}
```

> I want to assign the values of every key as the function that shows the turtle program but without it running

Comment: hi, you could have a list of functions like `[palito, rayito]`

Comment: You can reference functions by name simply by writing their names without adding the parenthesis for calling them.